# Get "#myDiv:hover" style from specified in CSS-file with jQuery or similar

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, pseudo-class

I need to check if any ":hover" or ":active" styles are specified for some elements in the CSS rules. I need to loop through these elements if they have the rules specified, on `$(document).ready` to add some events for ie6 which do not support ":hover" or ":active" on div's.

I could add a class to the specific elements that needs to be "fixed" but I would like the script to be able to work based on what is specified in the CSS. That would make it more dynamic...

`$('#elem').is(":hover")` won't help to select the element since I need to know before actually hovering.

Maybe this is hard/impossible to do without loading the file "ajax-style" which is not an option...

PS: yes, of course use of IE6 should not be encouraged, but China with 200 million XP machines and 22% IE6 (as of march 2014) is a very important market ([source](https://www.techinasia.com/windows-xp-now-dead-but-200-million-machines-in-china-still-using-it/)).

Comment: What `:hover` or `:active` styles are so crucial that you would go to such lengths to recreate them in a 13 year old browser? Don't get me wrong, I applaud your desire to support IE 6, but I am struggling to understand the need to support it *to that degree*.

Comment: Well, I see your point as well... Would it have been for just one page I might have ignored this, however... If I get the fix in order I will be able to re-use it on some huge sites that are critical to work well in China. So why not give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could scan all the css rules for selectors containing `:hover` or `:active`, then process the `cssText` of those rules however you like.

```
var iSheet, sheet, iRule, rules, rule;
for (iSheet=0; iSheet<document.styleSheets.length; iSheet++) {
    sheet = document.styleSheets[iSheet];
    rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules;
    for (iRule=0; iRule<rules.length; iRule++) {
        rule = rules[iRule];        
        if (rule.selectorText.indexOf(":hover") > -1) {
            console.log(rule.cssText);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/t15wxea3/).

Comment: Hi,thanks for this. A nice solution, I tried it in IE6 and I think I would be able to make it work. However I think that parsing through all rules might be bad for the performance of the browser, especially when the CSS is massive which it is in my case. This time I will go for a more simple approach. I will just loop through all elements in my "selection" and add the hover event/.hover class regardless of, if any hover style is specified in the CSS. 

The best thing would be if I could loop through my selection i.e. $(".ie6fix") and somehow check for a hover style only on these elements.Tnx

Comment: You're welcome. An idea: if the css is huge, you could separate it to two files (a hover.css and a nonhover.css) with this code once, save the two files, and use those. That way you could limit the runtime processing to the smaller hover.css.